# Issues on Rails 7 stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I wanna know why Rails doesn't create the `.css` files in `app/assets/stylesheets` when I generate, for example, a new scaffold. The only file in `app/assets/stylesheets` is `application.css`

[my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLjoe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was removed here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43110

Explanation in the pull request:

> Modern web applications are more likely than not to use a CSS framework like Tailwind, Bootstrap, or Bulma. Rails shouldn't be generating per-model stylesheets as though we were still writing everything by hand.
>
> Also, Sass has chosen to focus exclusively on dart-sass, which requires all manner of dependencies that Rails won't adopt by default. So decrease our reliance on Sass, and move it to being an optional extra.